# Bootstrap button troubleshooting in Laravel 9

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, laravel-9, laravel-jetstream

How do I achieve the default Jetstream Livewire logged-in button in my `home.blade.php,` which is a Bootstrap template?

I tried several other functions, such as the if and else functions, and then used them, but I didn't achieve that. I used Laravel 9 and Jetstream 3.

```
@guest
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="btn btn-primary ml-lg-3" href="{{ route('login') }}">Login</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="btn btn-primary ml-lg-3" href="{{ route('register') }}">Register</a>
    </li>
@endguest

@auth
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('dashboard') }}">Dashboard</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <form method="post" action="{{ route('logout') }}">
            @csrf
            <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('logout') }}" onclick="event.preventDefault(); document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                Logout
            </a>
        </form>
    </li>
@endauth
```